# How can I generate a list starting with the first value in a range?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a string that indicates a range of values: `"A1C - A1H"`

I need to be able to create a list of all the values in that range, meaning: `['A1C', 'A1D', 'A1E', 'A1F', 'A1G', 'A1H']`

```
list = []
range = "A1C - A1H"
code = range[:2]
range_end = range[-3:]
for letter in ascii_uppercase:
    order = code+letter
    if order not in range_end:
            list.append(order)
    else:
            list.append(range_end)
            break
print(list)
```

The code runs, as is but it creates a list with the first 'A1A', 'A1B' values which I don't need:

```
['A1A', 'A1B', 'A1C', 'A1D', 'A1E', 'A1F', 'A1G', 'A1H']
```

How can I generate the list starting with 'A1C'?

Comment: you need to start the "for letter in ascii_uppercase" two char later

Answer (score 1):

Start the "for letter in ascii_uppercase" two char later

```
list = []
range = "A1C - A1H"
code = range[:2]
range_end = range[-3:]
count = 0
for letter in ascii_uppercase:
    if count > 1:
        order = code+letter
        if order not in range_end:
            list.append(order)
        else:
            list.append(range_end)
            break
    count += 1
print(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in `ord` and `chr` functions with a list comprehension instead to generate the desired list:

```
l = ['A1' + chr(i) for i in range(ord('C'), ord('H') + 1)]
```

`l` would become:

```
['A1C', 'A1D', 'A1E', 'A1F', 'A1G', 'A1H']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare letter code and start loop when it is greater than starting point of string :

```
import string

def generate(string_data):
    code      = string_data[:2]
    range_end = string_data[-3:]
    sub_range = string_data[2:-6]
    result=[]
    for letter in string.ascii_uppercase:
        if ord(letter)< ord(sub_range):
            pass
        elif code+letter == range_end:
            result.append(code+letter)
            break
        else:
            result.append(code+letter)
    return result
```

output:

```
['A1C', 'A1D', 'A1E', 'A1F', 'A1G', 'A1H']
```

alternative solution:
This is not best solution but you can also slice the list from list in your code:

```
list_data = []
range_data = "A1C - A1H"
code = range_data[:2]
range_end = range_data[-3:]
for letter in string.ascii_uppercase:
    order = code+letter
    if order not in range_end:
            list_data.append(order)
    else:
            list_data.append(range_end)
            break
print(list_data[list_data.index(range_data[:3]):list_data.index(range_end)+1])
```

Note: Don't use `list` and `range` as variable name , They have special meaning in Python.